# Populate database with data from a form

Tags: php, mysql

I want to fill all the fields in my database by getting the ones inputted on my form but it won't fill my database.

I don't know what's wrong with it:

```
    <?php

    $handle = mysql_connect("", "root" , "");       
    return mysql_select_db("bonggarden", $handle);  

    $SQL = "INSERT INTO table1(fname,femail,fphone,fmsg) 
       values('".$_POST['name']."','".$_POST['email']."','".$_POST['number']."','".$_PO  ST['message']."')";

mysql_query($SQL);

?>
```

here is my form

```
    <form id="main-contact-form" accept-charset="utf-8" class="" method="post" >
                <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Name *</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" required="required">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Email *</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" required="required">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Phone *</label>
                        <input type="text" name="number" id="number" class="form-control">
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-5">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Message *</label>
                        <textarea name="message" id="message" required="required" class="form-control" rows="8"></textarea>
                    </div>                        
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" required="required">Submit Message</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: have you considered check error generated by mysql_query function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php


    $fname = $_POST['name'];
    $femail = $_POST['email'];
    $fphone = $_POST['number'];
    $fmsg = $_POST['message'];


    $handle = mysql_connect("localhost", "root" , "");       
    mysql_select_db("bonggarden", $handle);  

    $SQL = "INSERT INTO table1(fname,femail,fphone,fmsg) values('$fname','$femail','$fphone','$fmsg')";
    mysql_query($SQL);

?>
```

// if it still not working echo the variable $fname, $femail, $fphone, $fmsg check value is proparly getting in veriable or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
return mysql_select_db("bonggarden", $handle);
```

to

```
mysql_select_db("bonggarden", $handle);
```

The return is exiting the code before you execute the insert...

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the 'return' in:

```
 return mysql_select_db("bonggarden", $handle);
```

You may also consider adding the location of your server to your 'mysql_connect' function. EX:

```
 mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
```

A couple of suggestions too:

1.) Organizationally, assigning your values from $_POST to variables might make it easier to see what values you are sending to your database.

2.) Add a die function that outputs a MySQL error if your code cannot be run. This can often help with debugging and finding out the general location of your error. EX:

```
mysql_query($SQL) or die(mysql_error());
```

3.) Finally, and this gets said a lot on this website, consider switching to MySQLi as traditional 'mysql_' commands are now deprecated for security reasons.